# RedisSessionStateStore Issue with multiple Websites

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, stackexchange.redis

I am using Microsoft **RedisSessionStateStore** to handle session storage for two applications hosted in the same domain.
**Note** - I have blocked my parent web.config from child inheritance.

I am getting an assembly missing error when I try to load child application(MVC) after an initial load of parent application(Website Project). Error I am getting is because, **RedisSessionStateStore** is trying to fetch an assembly from parent application and trying to de-serialize it.
Not quite sure why it want to do like that. Assembly name in the exception is also a bit complicated name and also it would be difficult to find as my parent application is a Website project (Not Webforms).
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It would be easy to help if you can provide a test app. You can send it to us on AzureCache@microsoft.com. Also check your app should have StackExchange.Redis.StorngName.dll

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply Siddharth. Unfortunately I might not be able to pass the code, It's our client code. I can explain the scenario a little more in detail.
I have a parent project, which is hosted under say, www.test.local.com,
then an MVC project, which is hosted as an application inside 
 www.test.local.com and can be accessed via www.test.local.com/mvc url.

Comment: Web.config entries are as following for both the projects: **<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="RedisSessionStateStore"> <providers> <add name="RedisSessionStateStore" type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider" port="6379" host="ourcacheserver" clientType="pooled" accessKey="ouraccesskey" ssl="false" applicationName="mytest" /> </providers> </sessionState>**

Comment: When I try to browse **www.test.local.com/mvc** I am getting an error **Unable to find assembly 'App_SubCode_CSCode.dry46rxm, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.** This weird assembly name is because of the Website project as parent application. CSCode is a folder that exist in the parent application. I am a bit confused here that why the child application want to serialize something that is not at all used for any session storage. –  Angel Roche 21 mins ago

Comment: It doesn't look like error from sessions state to me. It looks basic ASP.NET MVC related error.